# How to integrate Spring and Apache Jackrabbit?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-roo, jackrabbit, jcr

Can someone provide an example to integrate spring 3 and jackrabbit 2.5? If you please can provide spring configuration (applicationContext.xml) and also jackrabbit configuration (repository.xml) in example where oracle can be used as persistence manager.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question, you have at least three possible answers - spring and jackrabbit , spring and maven, jackrabbit and maven. Not to mention Oracle :-)

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Actually, want to integrate jackrabbit and Spring where maven configuration was required to download jars required and Oracle was mentioned so that can use Oracle for persistence. Anyway, question amended so if you can help in this regard would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Jackrabbit and Spring example from Apache wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExamplesPage